# Android: SharedPreferences adds an extra 4 blanks when you cancel an app instead of close it

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

## Problem details

Seen on

- API 30, Android Studio Emulator
- API 23, Xiaomi Redmi 3s
- API 10, Samsung Galaxy Ace 2

Open the app.
Enter "abc" and a '\n' (newline).
Close the app.
Open it again.

Expected:
The EditText holds "abc\n".

Observed:
As expected.

Now cancel the app in the task manager.
Open it again.

Expected:
The EditText holds "abc\n".

Observed:
The EditText holds "abc\n    ".

Where do these 4 blanks after '\n' come from ?

## My code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText note;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefEditor = prefs.edit();
        note = new EditText(this);
        setContentView(note);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        note.setText(prefs.getString("note", ""));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        prefEditor.putString("note", note.getText().toString());
        prefEditor.commit();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

## Not perfect but reasonable solution

In onPause() - as @Harsh0021 suggested - I'll delete all leading and trailing white space with trim(). Then in onResume(), I'll add a '\n' in case SharedPreferences returns any text.

By the way, I use commit() instead of apply() because it's good enough and in API 1 instead of 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyy!!

First

Change

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        prefEditor.putString("note", note.getText().toString());
        prefEditor.commit();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

To

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        prefEditor.putString("note", note.getText().toString().trim());
        prefEditor.apply();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Then, That's all

Comment: Thanks, that was fast. Yes, with the trim() there's no '\n' at the end. And then it works and doesn't save any extra blanks. But I must save the EditText text as it is, not dropping anything. So, is this a bug in SharedPreferences ? Because it shouldn't behave like that. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: see, trim(); erases the spaces that user might have given mistakenly and you don't wanna add the spaces. And that spaces are a waste. Just think about it.

Comment: No no no, misunderstanding. There are no extra spaces in the user's input, just "abc\n". And I MUST not drop that ending '\n' if it's there. But trim() deleted all whitespace, incl. '\n'.

Comment: Not perfect but reasonable: In onPause() - as you suggested - I'll delete all leading and trailing white space with trim(). Then in onResume(), I'll add a '\n' SharedPreferences returns any text. - Thanks again.